# How does a newbie install a Ubuntu dual boot on an computer with XP?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, windows-xp

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 (32-bit) as a dual boot on my laptop which is running XP.  I managed to create a bootable USB stick, and to boot the laptop from that.  When offered the choice between "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu" I first chose "Try" and was able to try out various features of Ubuntu.  So far, so good.  Then I started again, this time choosing "Install Ubuntu", which gave me only two choices: either to Replace XP by Ubuntu (which I don't want), or to do "Something else", which sent me to a screen which seemed to be requiring me to partition the disc.  This is no good for me because I know very little about partitions, and anyway don't know how to use this rather enigmatic screen.  I note that the example on the "Install Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS" web page suggests that (a) the "Something else" choice is for advanced users (clearly not me!), and (b) there should be a 3rd choice: "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" (which I assume will create a partition for me).  How do I get access to this third choice?  Any other suggestions?

The hard drive is 149 GB, with 103 GB free space

Comment: How big in the hard drive (how much space is available in XP)? **Back-up** your data before you install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply download [Wubi - Windows Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) and make partition from your widows with free space depends your need. And install the wubi.exe from windows, here you can select drive, allocate virtual space as per your need, create username password and finaly install. If you have iso file place it which drive you select for Ubuntu. Else it will download directly from internet.

It's the simplest way to install [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I did this two weeks ago on my mom's computer. I believe after the 'Something else' you have the choice to install it alongside. Partitions are just ways that your computer logically separates drives (in this case). Simple example: So if you have Drive 1 with 50 GB, you split it into 2 partitions that are the same size, you would have Drive 1 with 25 GB, and Drive 2 with 25 GB. As long as you have room on the drive with XP for Ubuntu, you can partition it safely. You will get a new default boot loader (GRUB), which will let you choose which OS to boot into.

With the available space you will be fine doing a 30 GB or more partition and be completely safe. (The file system ext4, will probably be safest)

Note: After you install Ubuntu, XP will do a system check, with a message like there was a compromise to disk integrity. There wasn't XP just got scared of Ubuntu. (In reality, it had a record of how large the partition was, and noticed the size changed)

Check this again: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)  around step 7 or so.